# Is the product of two ideals in a number field order strictly contained in the two ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ be an arbitrary order in a number field and let $\mathfrak{p}, \mathcal{I} \subsetneq \mathcal{O}$ be proper $\mathcal{O}$-ideals such that $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime. Is it true that $\mathfrak{p} \mathcal{I} \neq \mathcal{I}$?

Clearly this is true in $\mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}_K$ by cancellation of ideals, but the cancellation of ideals does not hold in general in arbitrary sub-orders. This statement seems simple enough, but I cannot seem to find a convincing proof or counter-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\mathfrak p I = I$. Localize at $\mathfrak p$, so then we can apply Nakayama's lemma which says that $I_{\mathfrak p} = 0$. Since $\mathcal O$ is an integral domain this is clearly not possible unless $I= 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $PI=I\ne 0$ then $$(PO_K)(IO_K)=IO_K$$
which implies that $PO_K=O_K$ so that $P$ is contained in no maximal ideal of $O_K$ thus in no maximal ideal of $O$ ie. $1\in P$ and $P=O$.

Comment: This leaves out the case $I=0$ where the claim is in fact true

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on the statement "thus in no maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$"? Does that mean that all proper $\mathcal{O}$-ideals are contained in a maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$?

Comment: @ZacharyPepin If $P$ is a proper ideal of $O$ then it is contained in a maximal ideal of $O$ thus in a maximal ideal of $O_K$ thus $PO_K$ is a proper ideal of $O_K$

Comment: @reruns Hmm, I am afraid I don't see why this is true. It doesn't seem to be true of rings in general (i.e. $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$). Why is it true for orders in a number field?

Comment: @ZacharyPepin that fact is (I think) true. It definitely depends on the fact that the maximal order is integral over the smaller order. See Theorem 5.10 in Atiyah-Macdonald. There could be a more elementary approach to this fact.